# I host an Angular app on AWS S3 via a Cloudfront distribution. I want to setup a staging distribution: how do I change my CodePipeline workflow?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, aws-codepipeline

I learned that AWS Cloudfront now supports continued deployment:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/continuous-deployment.html

I would like to use this before I release a major update to my app, in order to roll it out slowly and catch any unforeseen issues early.

My current deployment happens via AWS CodePipeline: after building my app, it is deployed directly to the AWS S3 bucket to which the Cloudfront distribution is tied.

I couldn't find any documentation on how to change my CodePipeline configuration to account for a staging Cloudfront distribution.

Ideally, I would like the following setup:

- Normally, things work as before (as I don't often release major updates that need a gradual roll out), so the default behavior would be to automatically promote the staging distribution to production after every release.
- In case I exceptionally want a gradual roll out, it's okay to do things manually: I would go into Cloudfront, change some settings, make my release, and then gradually increase the roll out over a few days, until I reach 100%, I'm happy with the release, and restore the settings to behave as the point above.

Can anyone suggest how to tackle this scenario?

Thanks!